# consume parameter of jQuery.load from html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I use the following `jQuery.Load` to load external html which contains js functions:

```
$("#feeds").load("feeds.html", {limit: 25})
```

How can I consume the parameter from the html page?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need server support and some sort of templating system (where the server passes the parameter to the template, or its renderer) if you want to access it. Otherwise, you'll need to postprocess the response from the load yourself.

Comment: you'll have to use something like `$.get()` and install a callback which will postprocess the HTML and insert it into the element.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access it from your HTML file, then I suggest sending the 'limit' variable by using GET, instead of POST, which you are doing.

In otherwords, you can GET by doing this:

```
$("#feeds").load("feeds.html?limit=25")
```

Then you can parse 'location.search' to get your querystring value.

If you are using ASP.NET, then it is really simply to use a bit of server-side code to do something like:

```
<script>
    var limit = '<%=Request.Params["limit"]%>';
</script>
```

HTH,
SR

Comment: From what I understood GET is only for string, how can I pass js variable? I'm not working with ASP.NET it is a a simple call from js to HTML

Comment: You would need to convert the JSON to querystring format, and then on the other end, using the approach for GET as I already explained, you would then convert (decode) back to JSON and then parse the JSON using JQuery extension. It is very messy. It is why, people that are trying to do what you are doing, use the QueryString (GET) method. I thought my response would have helped but the downvote proved otherwise.